# Introduction to Internet Advertising for Web Developers

Tags: ads

I have been a web developer for several years, but have never been privy to "ins" and "outs" of web-based advertising. When you search online for introductory material on internet advertising, unless you know the right buzzwords to search for (which I don't) you only come up with literature that target either: (a) the total laymen, or (b) "mom and pop shop" type website owners that don't do any of their own coding. Sites that tell you about the basics of banner ad networks, and IAB size guidelines, and so forth.

What I am interested in is a technical introduction to web-based advertising. Say I have a website and I want to use some real estate on each one of my pages for advertisements.

- Where do I start?
- Do I set up an account somewhere and program divs/spans in my page to hit some banner ad server?
- Do I download and configure some script on my web server?

What I'm really looking for is both a broad and deep insight into all the advertising options out there, and how one actually rigs up these ad systems to their site: everything from AdSense to exchange networks, pay per click models, and everything in between.

If anyone knows of this kind of literature, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please spend a few minutes reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for what questions are appropriate for this site. A general rule is that if it's not a question directly related to writing your own application or library, or using a programming related tool or library, it's not on-topic here. Thanks. :)

Comment: I disagree. This site is also about promoting best practices in software engineering, which you cannot deny. My question is concerned with the technical aspects (and thus best practices) of engineering an advertising component for your web application to work with external ad servers. In no way shape or form is this off topic. :)

Comment: Yes, I can. There's a [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) for general (non-code specific) programming discussions. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information about which questions are on-topic here. Sticking to those guidelines helps keep this site useful and uncluttered. Thanks.

Comment: This seems more like an appropriate question for the webmasters stackexchange.

Comment: I disagree with closing this thread.  I mean, how are developers to get paid if not by salary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it however you like, from a technical perspective. The online advertising world is very, very broad and there is a great deal of variety. The hardest part, however, is getting advertisers. Without people paying for you to advertise their products/services, it doesn't do you any good.

I would suggest signing up for an account with an advertising company, such as [Google AdSense](http://www.google.com/adsense/start/). They take care of matching up advertisers with web properties, and it's very simple to provide the needed hooks. They have everything very well documented and it's very easy to get up and running. I'm pretty sure that the AdSense signup process even walks you through what you need to do, which is as simple as adding additional HTML to your page(s).

Trying to find your own advertisers and implement your own solution is just going to be a giant waste of time *in the majority of cases* because the market is so saturated with many better options for advertisers to use.

In the end, the best way to get info on how to integrate with an ad network is to simply contact them and ask. Most of the reputable ones already have good documentation on how to put their ads on your site.

---

In general, the primary way ad networks work is that you add HTML to your page that references some resource via a URL (often with your account number or similar identifier) on a server that the ad network controls. The resource might be an image, a video, a chunk of JavaScript, or anything else really (an iFrame is another common one).

In most cases, it will be a chunk of JavaScript or an iFrame and the script will get an ad off of their network and set it inside a link. This link is usually a link back to their server, which then redirects the user clicking it to whatever destination the ad is driving traffic to.

By hitting a resource on their server, they are **counting the number of "impressions" or "views"** that particular piece of advertising got from your site, and by routing the click through their server, they are **counting the number of clicks**. Since you send them your account ID when you request the resource, they can associate this all with your account and **pay you based on "cost-per-click" (CCP) and/or number of impressions**.

Other examples of non-standard ads (eg. a banner somewhere) include ad networks that use a script to scan the text content of your pages and selectively turn some words into links, often with larger ads that pop up when the user's mouse goes over them. A variation on this are the ads that pop up when you first enter a site, or ones that "attach" to the users' cursor for a specified amount of time.

All of these examples, however, are rather invasive and **will likely piss your users off and will reduce the number of users you have on your site**, which is a ***BAD THING***. Google has done lots and lots of research regarding effective ad placement, including things like size, color, differentiation from the rest of the site content, etc. and they make much of this information available through the AdSense documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply cdeszaq - I have and will continue to investigate AdSense and how it works! I'm still trying to wrap my head around banner ad networks and how to integrate with them technically. Again, I'm not afraid to do my own homework, I've just been hitting brick walls everywhere I turn looking for literature here. If you know of any major ad/affiliate networks that publish their tech specs (and how to integrate with them), please send them my way!

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide additional information and examples. If this is helpful, an up-vote is appreciated.