# Strip all ADVERTISING CODE from my HTML?

Tags: strip, ads

My skill in coding HTML is slightly above newbie level though my CSS is improving daily so I don't even know if this can be done. Although I have no Python, Php, Ruby, Javascript, Perl, Fortran **buzzer!** (just want to make sure you're still awake big guy) I am willing to learn. The slice below is the first 970 characters — .003 percent — of the 365,937 characters comprising its one style alone. It is these and other *Wall of Advertising Code* blocks I aspire to **delete**:

```
<style type="text/css">#Ad2, #AdText, #Ad_Top, #Adbanner, #Adfox_Banner, #Ads, #AdvertFieldBottom, #AdvertFieldCenter, #AdvertFieldTop, #Advertisement, #AdvertisingTopLine, #BanHolder28-1, #BannerGBottom, #BannerGCenter, #BannerGIMG, #BannerGTop, #BannerH2Left, #BannerHIMG, #BannerHLeft, #BannerUnderBroChat, #JaboxAdBarOuter, #METABAR_IFRAME, #MarketGidComposite1001, #PopUpWnd, #PopWin, #PopWin_popupsu_notds, #RichBanner_center, #__adIframe, #ad-200, #ad-slides, #ad2, #ad4, #ad7, #adHeadBanner, #adL, #adP, #adWrapper, #ad_help_link, #ad_hide_mask_ad_0, #ad_hide_mask_ad_1, #adbns, #adf_notifiers_wrap, #adsCSS, #advRightBox, #advbroker_place_1, #advbroker_place_10, #advbroker_place_2, #advbroker_place_3, #advbroker_place_4, #advbroker_place_5 { display: none!important; }
#advbroker_place_6, #advbroker_place_7, #advbroker_place_8, #advbroker_place_9, #advertbox, #advertising_floater, #advertisment, #advrich, #advunder-top, #adzerk3, #app-banners, . . .</style>
```

I frequently save HTML pages for my own private reference and I'd like to know if there are any offline¹ widgets/ apps/ macros/ techniques that I could use to **strip**

1. the file's **advertising code**, and
2. all **non-content data code** (scripts, forms, events etc.)

I'd like to keep the visual style of the author's page but remove the bloat and I figure if the towering level of talent on stackoverflow can't find a solution then *nobody* can. I have rudimentary knowledge of *Regular Expressions* and with the exception of Notepad++ I am a regular user of the assets below:

- Macromedia's Dreamweaver 8
- Textpad (ver 8.1)
- Ultra-Edit-32 (ver 13)
- Notepad++
- Nir Sofer's [magnificent suite of tools](http://nirsofer.net)
- SysInternals's (likewise) [suite of tools](http://sysinternals.com)

Can it be done? Thanks everyone. :)

¹for privacy reasons I'd like to avoid an online service

Comment: You could use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) along with javascript to look for `#ad{..}` up to the `,` and remove them. Of course there's going to be a bit more to that. You can't simply look for `#Ad` as a non-ad element could be named `#Additional-info` and that would be caught and removed. You could use regular expressions to save anything with `#ad{..}` to an array and then look for `id={matched}`. If the match matches an `iframe` (usually what ads reside in, you can remove it from the styles and HTML.

Comment: I take your point. Aren't these numerous ad services collected somewhere, like a wiki so that I could just run a macro in Textpad and weed them out?  It may not get all of them but I would think it would strip a huge volume of them . . .

Comment: I am not sure if they're collected anywhere. Looks like you have a databank to start.

Comment: In this thread — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743524/how-are-advertisements-from-third-party-ad-providers-delivered-to-a-web-page?rq=1 — I just learned that these advertisers typically use *javascript* or *iframes* (?) If that's so, would those be the search parameters? But then how would I distinguish them from code related to the content?

Comment: Well, like I mentioned in my comment, you take the matched term in the css, `#Ad2`, remove the `#` and see if it matches `id="Ad2"`, if it does remove that element or style tag.

Comment: I'm sorry Press, I don't understand.

Comment: Give me a minute to write an answer/example with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is crude, but as Wild Beard mentioned there just isn't an easy way to get rid of this ad crap. **Use a fixed-pitch/monospace font** and a robust text editor with **line numbering** options (I did this in Textpad but I'm pretty sure Don Ho's FREE Notepad++ could do this as well).

1. SAVE A BACKUP OF YOUR ORIGINAL!
2. remove all word wrapping
3. align all lines of text to the left margin
4. eliminate all double-or-more vertical spacing

*You should now have a large block of text, left-aligned, and single-spaced*

5. at the first character position of each line insert line-numbering, followed by a TAB
6. zero fill your number column so your digits align

*Sorting on the first character you don't want line # 5 to be grouped with line # 50001*

6. visually scroll for the really lengthy lines and begin to experiment with sorting on their positions

What you're doing is grabbing the longest of the advertising lines and isolating them for deletion. Be prepared to do this more than once. And don't sweat getting the document back to its original order. That's why you numbered the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof of concept. You'll still need to determine the read/write to file after removing the elements etc or styles. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jv23fjf7/1/)

However, like I mentioned in my comment, this will match `#additional-info` as well. I did add a check to see if the element was an `iframe` which should narrow down errors a bit.

```js
var matched_classes = [],
  regex = /(#ad)\w+/gmi,
    style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

style.forEach(function(item) {
 matched_classes = item.innerHTML.match(regex);
});

matched_classes.forEach(function(item) {
 var el = document.getElementById(item.replace('#', ''));
  if ( el != null && el.nodeName === 'IFRAME' ) {
   el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
  }
});
```

```html
<style type="text/css">#Ad2, #AdText, #Ad_Top, #Adbanner</style>
<iframe id="Ad2" src="https://www.w3schools.com">

</iframe>

<div id="AdText">Something not removed hopefully.</div>
```

### Edit

As you mentioned in your comment you have no idea how to implement this. There's no simple and easy way to do it. You can get started [here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) on how to create files with javascript but Javascript likely isn't going to be your best bet. From your list of languages in the question Python may be your best bet, sadly, I don't know Python.

You could copy this code I've created and paste it into the bottom of your files, open the file in your browser, view source, copy, and save the new file as it should remove any `iframe` element with a matching `id` from a `<style>` tag. That's a bit tedious. But for someone who doesn't have any experience that may be your best place to start - you know short of writing out the entire solution for you.

```
<script>
var matched_classes = [],
            regex = /(#ad)\w+/gmi,
        style = document.querySelectorAll('style');

    style.forEach(function(item) {
        matched_classes = item.innerHTML.match(regex);
    });

    matched_classes.forEach(function(item) {
        var el = document.getElementById(item.replace('#', ''));
      if ( el != null && el.nodeName === 'IFRAME' ) {
          el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Press you are going to kill me but I have no idea how to implement this. Also, when I trigger Stack's _Run code snippet_ I get an error (just mentioning).  This is a javascript function? How is it interacting with my bloated HTML? Am I starting with a **new** HTML file? -or- placing this directly into the code of the bloated **original**? and does the result output to a **separate file**?  I can study the structure from your example, I just need to know how I would get started!! can't thank you enough :)

Comment: @semicodin I've updated my answer. There's no simple way to do this, especially with javascript and being that you're a beginner.

Comment: I'm fooling around with macros and regex and if Stack will let me I will post a solution (I'm being warned not to add to Comments)

Comment: @semicodin by all means go for it! If you manage to find an answer to your own question there's nothing wrong with adding it and marking it as correct. Sorry if my answer wasn't much help!

Comment: You're awesome Press. I certainly will post it. Want to hear a wild idea I just had?  Dig this: Search for any data exceeding (oh, let's say) **5,000 characters without a space** muahahaha . . .

Comment: I've had some luck using Nir Sofer's HtmlDocEdit http://nirsoft.net/utils/html_doc_edit.html

Answer (score 0):

If you find these strange style definitions in the shadow-root of your browser:
This CSS is dynamically added to each website by 
Adguard Adblocker. The tool sets all kinds of "#banner..." or "#ad..." etc to "display:none !important".

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adguard-adblocker/

Comment: Gerfreid, that's really valuable information to know! I can't thank you enough for sharing it. It's going into my toolbox right now.